# How to update child component’s props?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components

I have some todo list app and it gets data from server.Then i have a search child component that takes his parent’s state as it’s props and then when you are searching something it filters and updates parent’s state passing it’s new filtered state.

Until there everything is okay but when i am trying to delete something from that searched list and then i am searching same thing it gives me already deleted note.

Simply i think its not updating search component’s props when it’s parent’s state is already updated after deletion.

How can i solve this?

I am using React JS )

Comment: If you add the code of the relevant components, it will help you get an answer. As it stands, we can only speculate what the problem could be. You could create a snippet or a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io)

Comment: This is my main page for todo lists [link](https://github.com/danomov/AuthenticatableTodoListApp/blob/master/Full%20Stack/todo_client/src/Todos/todos.js) and this is my search bar component [link](https://github.com/danomov/AuthenticatableTodoListApp/blob/master/Full%20Stack/todo_client/src/SearchBar/searchBar.js)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need is `componentDidUpdate` in the `SearchBar` component :

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    if (this.props.data !== prevProps.data) {
        this.setState({data: this.props.data ,filteredData: this.props.data});
    }
}
```

A better solution is not to store `data` as state in `SearchBar`, juste access it directly from the props

Comment: Yeah i just did it but with componentWillReceiveProps method.But i looked for this.Thanks a lot ))